# Django not showing variables

Tags: django, variables

I am starting on my journey with Django but have hit a problem with it showing variables. In principle I want a list of buildings from which I have a Home page that shows a list of all of them as links that take you to an page that shows the detail of each one.

in models.py I have:

```
class Build(models.Model):
    building_name = models.CharField( max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    #other details
```

in views.py I have:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import Build

def home(request):
    builds = Build.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'Home.html', {'builds':builds,})

def building_detail(request,build_id):
    #return HttpResponse(f'<p> building number {build_id}</p>')
    build = get_object_or_404(Build, id=build_id),
    return render(request, 'Building_detail.html', {'build':build,})
```

In URLs.py I have:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from Buildings import views

urlpatterns.py = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('buildings/<int:build_id>/', views.building_detail, name= 'building_detail'),
]
```

For the Home.html file I have:

```
    <p>Home view from template</p>
    <div>
        {% for build in builds %}
            <div class="buildingname">
                <a href="{% url 'building_detail' build.id %}">
                <h3>{{build.building_name|capfirst}}</h3>
                </a>
                </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

and for Building_detail.html this

```
    <div>  
        <h3>{{build.building_name|capfirst}}</h3>
        <p>building view from template is this working</p>
        <h3>does this {{build.building_name|capfirst}} work</h3>
        <p>{{build.address}}
    </div>
```

the Home page works fine a shows a list of all the buildings in the database. Each one is a link to a Bulding_detail page but the building detail page only shows:

building view from template is this working

does this work

I have added the #return HttpResponse(f'

building number {build_id}

') bit to views to test thing and swapping that section in works fine, displaying the right building number. In the Building_detail.html file, I have several versions of the variables I want shown to try different thing but none have worked

What have I done wrong or missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the trailing comma, otherwise you are wrapping the result in a singleton tuple:

```
def building_detail(request, build_id):
    # return HttpResponse(f'<p> building number {build_id}</p>')
    build = get_object_or_404(Build, id=build_id)  # 🖘 no comma
    return render(
        request,
        'Building_detail.html',
        {
            'build': build,
        },
    )
```